# multisections of grassmannian bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $\pi:G_X(r,N)\rightarrow X$ is a Grassmannian bundle associated to a vector bundle $E\rightarrow X$. Is it possible to construct a smooth/normal multisection
of $\pi$. Ie. is there a finite morphism $Z\rightarrow X$ (outide codim atleast two)
where $Z\subset G_X(r,N)$.

thanks..

Answer (score 3):

I suppose your $X$ is smooth, or, say, normal? In that case, it is (trivially) possible to construct a *section* defined outside a set of codimension $\geq 2$. Indeed your fibration is locally trivial, so there is a Zariski open subset $U\subset X$ and a section $s:U\rightarrow G_X(r,N)$. Now since $X$ is normal and $\pi : G_X(r,N)\rightarrow X$ proper, $s$ extends outside a set of codimension $\geq 2$.

Comment: To obtain a finite morphism as in the question, the normal asssumption is not necessary: first normalize $X$ and then apply the construction  (assuming of course the normalization is finite, e.g. $X$ is of finite type over a field). If $X$ is irreducible and reduced, the resulting $Z\to X$ will be finite and *birational* over an open subscheme containing the points of codinemsion 1.